# Self-plagiarism and supplementary information

Tags: self-plagiarism

I am curious if it is acceptable to produce an identical (or at least only slightly edited) account of a particular, known methodology in the supplementary information of two submitted journal articles, or if this would count as self-plagiarism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods sections (supplementary or otherwise) are one of the few places where self-plagiarism may not apply.  This is because the typical format for a methods section is not narrative (for which creativity is expected) but a highly compressed sort of recipe (e.g. "DHT5a cells in LB, grown in 96-well plates, 150 mL per well, at 37C for 18 hours while shaking at 300 rpm.").  In this form, method sections are essentially a computer program to be executed by a human, and as such the question of self-plagiarism is irrelevant, just like it is if you attach a computer program to your supplementary information.

If you have a "long-form" method section, however, where you give a narrative explanation of an approach, its reasoning and justification, how it relates to the experiments, etc., then the narrative aspects *are* expected to show originality and self-plagiarism does apply.  This is because you have explanatory text that should be contextually adapted to the rest of the paper, an using it in a new paper changes the context and should thus change the text.

For an example illustrating this distinction, [here is the supplementary section from on of my own recent papers](http://jakebeal.com/Publications/ACSSynBio14-CircuitPrediction-Supplementary.pdf).  Section 9, "Additional Methods" is a "recipe section" for which I would not be concerned with the question of self-plagiarism.  All of the other sections are "narrative sections" where one does need to be concerned about self-plagiarism.